# Length of Line Segment within Intersecting Circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose two circles of radius = 1 intersect one another's center and there are two points where these circles themselves intersect, at point A and B.  If a line segment were drawn between point A and B, what is the length of that line segment?

See image below:

[image]

Comment: length of AB is $\sqrt(3)$. $$2(\sqrt{1^2 - (\frac{1}{2})^2})$$

Comment: Don't forget to show your attempts.

Comment: Hint: mark the centers of the two circles on the figure, and note the two equilateral rectangles.

Comment: How would you calculate the area of the overlapping region between these circles?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the pythagoras theorem:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What do you get if you draw a line segment between the centers of both circles and from each center to Point A?